# How to Integrate $\int \frac{cos(z)}{z^2(z-1)}dz$ for $|z|<\frac{1}{3}$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

My attempt

$$f(z)= \frac{\cos z}{(z-1)}$$

$$f^{\prime}(z)= -\frac{\sin z}{(z-1)}-\frac{\cos z}{(z-1)^2}$$

$$\int \frac{cos(z)}{z^2(z-1)}dz=2\pi if^{\prime}(0)=2\pi i\left( -\frac{\sin 0}{(0-1)}-\frac{\cos 0}{(0-1)^2}\right)= 2\pi i\left(-\frac{\sin 0}{(0-1)}-\frac{\cos 0}{(0-1)^2}\right)=-2\pi i$$

Is this correct?

Comment: By $|z|<\frac{1}{3}$ do you mean a contour around there?

Comment: It seems to me fine.

Comment: @Mark, Yes it is.

Comment: looks OK $\quad{}$